# How can I pass data to a viewcontroller and load it before pushing it onto Navigation stack?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a view controller with a collection view and when I click a cell, I pass a variable to another view controller, then push it onto the navigation stack.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nextVC", sender: self.userArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

This is how I send the variable:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)
     let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NextVC
     if let senderId = sender!.objectForKey("uId") {
          nextVC.userId = senderId as! String
     }
}
```

This next view controller (nextVC) has a lot of stuff on it.  I have done everything I can to optimize it but it still takes some time to load all the stuff.  Is there a way I can prepare for segue, pass the variable, and let the next vc do it's thing, then when it's done loading, actually segue to it? (or show it)?  I saw some other questions which talk about preloading view controllers but none of them dealt with passing a variable.  This variable is very important because all the stuff in the nextVC has to know this one variable (based on cell touched) or it won't be able to load.  I hope I explained this well enough, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access the `view` property of the `destinationViewController`, it will trigger the `view` to load.  Since you don't really need the `view`, just assign it to `_` to keep the compiler happy.

Try this:

```
 if let senderId = sender!.objectForKey("uId") {
      nextVC.userId = senderId as! String
      _ = nextVC.view
 }
```

This will trigger `viewDidLoad` to run before the segue happens.  Make sure your code to set up your `NextVC` is in `viewDidLoad` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes but won't it still segue right away?  Without giving it time to load?

Comment: Unless you're loading stuff in a background thread, I think the view will be loaded after `_ = nextVC.view` completes which is before the segue happens.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah it's not any different

Comment: Actually I have some stuff in viewdidappear.. maybe it doesn't load that part?

Comment: Yeah, `viewDidAppear` won't happen until after the segue.  Can you move that code to `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: YES OMG it worked.  I have been at this for like 2 days, and I tried pretty much what u said but I didn't realize that it hadn't worked because a lot of the stuff was in viewdidappear.  Thank you so much! I can't believe it was this easy

Comment: Glad I could help!