# Handling a remote notification by loading a viewController and passing data to it

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am super new in Xamarin.iOS and I tried to find my problem and how to handle notifications but all what I got is showing an alert examples.

Just like in whatsapp once you touch the notification that you get it would open a certain ViewController with the data, I would like to do something similar. Once i get a remote notification with a text on it , I want to show that text in the main ViewController. How to do that ?

I found some similar questions but they are either in Swift or Objective-c

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300144/passing-data-received-from-a-push-notification-from-the-appdelegate-to-a-viewcon), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112114/open-a-viewcontroller-from-remote-notification) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953609/how-can-i-pass-data-to-a-viewcontroller-and-load-it-before-pushing-it-onto-navig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //when you app in background and user click your notification
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var userInfo = launchOptions.ValueForKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey) as NSDictionary;
        if (userInfo != null)
        {
            var message = userInfo.ValueForKey(new NSString("yourTextKey")) as NSString;
            var vc = new MessageViewController();
            vc.TextView.Text = message;
            Window.RootViewController = vc;

        }
        else
        {
            Window.RootViewController = new OtherRootViewController();
        }
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        return true;
    }

    //when you app in foreground
    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        if (userInfo != null)
        {
            var message = userInfo.ValueForKey(new NSString("yourTextKey")) as NSString;
            var vc = new MessageViewController();
            vc.TextView.Text = message;
            Window.RootViewController.PresentViewController(vc, true, null);
        }
    }
```